# JBoss vs Tomcat - StringUtils.isEmpty

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, string-utils

I was developing using Tomcat and everything was doing perfect.

Now I switched to JBoss, and when the application reaches the StringUtils.isEmpty code, it finds a 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I tried using the same StringUtils as in the other project, but still didn't work.
Both times, it reads a null variable. But tomcat has no problem and jboss do.

Any idea?

JBoss AS 6.0

Tomcat 6.0

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: which StringUtils is that? And show the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a library clash.  If Tomcat uses the Apache Commons lang utilities, and JBOSS is using something else, you might have a problem.

We really need more information to tell what the problem is.

Comment: It takes fast fingers to beat you.

Comment: I think it would need to be different versions of the same StringUtils class.  Otherwise, you'd be seeing compilation errors I think.